# What does "You two wander off more than my stepson's left eye" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across this sentence in the TV-series 2 Broke Girls, [S06E13](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=30598) 00:12:48. But I don't get it.

And the context is:

> "Here you are. You two wander off more than my stepson's left eye. You're late for your scene."

Comment: This is probably intended to be a humorous reference to **amblyopia**.  As for the humor, the stereotypical relationship between step-parent and step-child is a fraught or a cold one, which is what causes the speaker to be so cavalier and callous about the condition.

Comment: Many sitcom punchlines are not standard idioms, but metaphors intended to amuse the audience, partly through surpirse. I wouldn't recommend using this one in everyday speech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a joke. It's not a common expression.

There are two things referred to as "wandering eye". First is a medical condition in which one eye doesn't point towards the object that the person is focussing on.  (The medical term is intermittant *strabismus*)

The second is a metaphor for someone who looks at women other than their wife/girlfriend, or someone who looks at women's bodies while talking to them.  (Or it could also be someone who looks at other men)

In the quote "Here you are." means "I have found you here", rather than the expression used when giving something to someone.

The rest is funny because it is rather shocking that someone would make a simile like "wander as much as (someone's) eye". Don't use this in everyday conversation.

Comment: I am still not getting it. Can you explain a bit about "*it is rather shocking that someone would make a simile like "wander as much as (someone's) eye"*"? I don't see "someone is trying to make a smile" in this context. Thanks!

Comment: @dan, "simile" is not "smile", a "simile" is a comparison, more direct than a metaphor. This show is a bit loose, and the women are wandering in a lot of different ways. It's probably not a funny joke if you didn't hear the "shock value," the immediate response to being told something.